# Total page views in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello everyone i think this is good question. I am using page counter script for my website but i want to see in my dashboard total page view not only one page total viwed.

I want Total page view HOW CAN I MAKE IT ?

This is my page counter code :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET `post_view` = `post_view`+1 WHERE post_id ='$page_id'");
```

This is my table: [Table images](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1399188_732584710103170_1530531287_o.jpg)

Comment: `SUM` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: Do you mean total pages views for the entire website combined? Not just as you said individual pages?

Comment: Total pages views for the entire website combined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_*` functions. Cause they are deprecated and get removed in one of the next versions of PHP.

For your problem have a look at the MySQL function [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

```
SELECT SUM(post_view) total_page_views FROM posts
```

Comment: I understand but how can i do this i don't know.

Comment: <?php include("connect.php");

?>
<div class="total_page_views">
             
             </div>

Comment: Thanks TİMESPLİNTER i solwed my problem my problem solved code is:
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(post_view) FROM posts");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['SUM(post_view)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  

?>